# Framer motion whileInView not animating correctly on mobile

Tags: reactjs, animation, css-animations, framer-motion

When switching to mobile view for android based devices or using a chromium-based mobile emulator, animations will be in the completed state before you scroll down in view.
This issue does not appear on Safari or while in desktop view.

Example code used on the website that appears off screen when the component has mounted.

```js
                <motion.div
                    variants={slideLeft(false)}
                    initial="initial"
                    whileInView="animate"
                    exit="exit"
                    transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
                    viewport={{ once: true }}
                >
```

The animation variant used

```js
/**
 * @param {boolean} cont default: true
 * @param {boolean} exit default: true
 * @param {string} customVal default: %
 * @return {import("framer-motion").MotionProps}
 */
const slideLeft = (cont = true, exit = true, customVal = "%") => {
    /**
     * @type {import("framer-motion").MotionProps}
     */
    const output = {
        initial: {
            x: `100${customVal}`,
        },
        animate: {
            x: 0,
        },
        exit: {
            x: `-100${customVal}`,
        },
    };
    if (!cont) output.exit = { x: `100${customVal}` };
    if (!exit) delete output.exit;
    return output;
};
export default slideLeft;
```

Comment: question: whileInView does not seem to work for me on safari. On Android it works fine. Does scroll animations with framer motion work for you on apple mobile devices?

Comment: @Magnus I never had an issue with animations on apple devices. It's strange that it has problems for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs when there is an overflow on the x-axis (right-hand side of the device).
Can be fixed by applying this CSS style. `overflow-x: hidden;`

```css
html,
body,
#root {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* Prevents overflow on the x-axis */
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```